# For loops that skips 0's in an array

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-for-loop

My code is quite long so I'll explain it.
I have an array (int [] num = {2,5,17,52,18,47,37,29,22};) that I'm looping through using a for loop I have another loop nested in the first for loop so that when i is at position 0 for example the other loop will loop through the rest of the array to see if a certain condition is met, if that condition is met the integer at the i will become zero. I have programmed my first for loop to skip over the zero and move on to the next value in the array however I am having some issues because I found that if there are two zeros (one after the other in a for loop)
Ex. (num = {2,5,***0,0***,18,47,37,29,22}; then the for loop will only skip over the first zero and move onto the next integer which is another zero, what i would like the code to do is skip over all zeros. How might I go about that?

Here is my code, the issue is with the num[i] = 0; code

```
String [] deck = {"A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","T","J","Q","K"};

        int [] num = {2,5,17,52,18,47,37,29,22};

        String suits = "";
        int fcard;
        String card = "";
        int fcard2;
        String card2 = "";


        for(int i = 0; i< num.length;i++) {

            if (num[i] == 0) {
                i++;
            }

            if (num[i] <=13) {
                suits = "Clubs";
                fcard = num[i] - 1;
                card = deck[fcard];
            }
            else if (num[i] >=14 && num[i] <=26) {
                suits = "Diamonds";
                fcard = num[i] - 14;
                card = deck[fcard];
            }
            else if (num[i] >=27 && num[i] <=39) {
                suits = "Hearts";
                fcard = num[i] - 27;
                card = deck[fcard];
            }
            else if (num[i] >=40 && num[i] <=52) {
                suits = "Spades";
                fcard = num[i] - 40;
                card = deck[fcard];
            }

            System.out.print(suits+":"+" "+card+" ");

            for (int j = i + 1 ; j < num.length;j++) {

                //if (j == num.length-1) {
                //break;
                //}

                if (num[j] == 0 && j!=num.length-1) {
                    j++;
                }

                if (num[j]<=13 && suits.equals("Clubs")) {
                    fcard2 = num[j] - 1;
                    card2 = deck[fcard2];
                    System.out.print(card2+" ");
                    num[j]=0;
                }
                else if ((num[j]>=14 && num[j] <=26) && suits.equals("Diamonds")) {
                    fcard2 = num[j] - 14;
                    card2 = deck[fcard2];
                    System.out.print(card2+" ");
                    num[j]=0;
                }
                else if ((num[j] >=27 && num[j] <=39) && suits.equals("Hearts")) {
                    fcard2 = num[j] - 27;
                    card2 = deck[fcard2];
                    System.out.print(card2+" ");
                    num[j]=0;
                }
                else if ((num[j] >=40 && num[j] <=52) && suits.equals("Spades")) {
                    fcard2 = num[j] - 40;
                    card2 = deck[fcard2];
                    System.out.print(card2+" ");
                    num[j]=0;
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: Can you give a sample input, output of your current program, and your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is currently in the form:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    if (num[i] == 0) {
        i++;
    }
    // do something for non-zeros
}
```

As you mention, that will clearly only skip 1 zero and then perform the 'do something' on the next element whether or not it is zero. That isn't what you want.

A simple solution would be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    if (num[i] != 0) {
        // do something for non-zeros
    }
}
```

Note: your model is going to cause a lot of issues if the complexity of your code increases. For example you are overloading your `num` array to do multiple things. I recommend you refactor to use enums for suits and face value and classes for cards and decks.